# convert Unix Time stamp and sort data in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a small database by date, my date table data is stored in time 2014-02-04 . how can I convert that and check it against todays date.

This is what I have but I am getting a few errors

```
$q = 'SELECT count(*) as count FROM SHOW WHERE date('Y-m-d', strtotime  
('SHOW_DATE') ='.$db->qstr(date()).' AND CONTACT='.$db->qstr($name);
if(!$rs = $db->execute($q)){
force_page('core', 'error&error_msg=MySQL Error: '.$db->ErrorMsg().'&menu=1');
exit;
} else {
$today_count = $rs->fields['count'];
$smarty->assign('today_count',$today_count);
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it stored as a `DATE` (like it should) or a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: You are using ' around the string and in the string without escaping it. Just look at your code and you see that the syntax highlighting becomes strange around Y-m-d on the first line

Comment: `WHERE SHOW_DATE = CURDATE()` should work fine. No need to involve PHP where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @h2ooooooo But he got to qote the table name `SHOW` with backticks too, because `SHOW` is a [reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: @VMai What? No? `SHOW_DATE` is a single column - it doesn't need backticks just because part of it is a reserved keyword. Same reason that a column named `SAND` wouldn't need backticks because it includes `AND` and `NOTE` wouldn't need backticks because it includes `NOT`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Have a look at the query: `SELECT count(*) as count FROM SHOW WHERE` ...

Comment: @VMai Ah yes - you're right that the table name needs to be back-quoted - I didn't even notice that part. Needing my morning coffee, apparently.

Comment: @VMai: [*...For example, COUNT is acceptable as a column name.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Only `SHOW` needs back ticks.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I've tried all the above but I get nothing

Comment: @user3620142 What's your new exact query? What happens if you execute it directly in the DB?

Comment: syntax error unexpected T_STRING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `show_date` to a date format using `FROM_UNIXTIME` function. And then compare the `date` part of it with your input date value.

**Example**:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM `SHOW`
 WHERE date( from_unixtime( `SHOW_DATE` ) ) = ? AND CONTACT=?
```

Use prepared statement to bind input values to the place holders.

Comment: "*it is stored as `DATE`*"

Comment: Yes. Then `show_date = curdate()` should work. And OP should clarify where the `unix_timestamp` comes into picture.

Comment: @user3620142: Cool... I posted answer without looking into discussions in comments. Answer was based on your posting title and the function expressions used in your code.

Comment: @user3620142: And the condition `date( show_date ) = curdate()` should work if `show_date` is of `datetime` or `timestamp`. If it is `date`, then you can directly compare.

Comment: I tried show_date = curdate() but getting error in console

Comment: it is stored as date only

Comment: I am getting that from here though not on the first line  force_page('core', 'error&error_msg=MySQL Error: '.$db->ErrorMsg().'&menu=1');

Comment: That is a PHP error. You might have not properly concatenated values or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

To find a row containing a [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/datetime.html) matching the current date, use [**CURDATE()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE col_date = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you are missing a big part of the query

Comment: @user3620142 Well I'm not trying to write your query for you. This is the logic that you need to answer your question.